# Tkinter python , cant get the value from scale object

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i am using Tkinter on python 2.7 , i am trying to get the value from the scale object by pressing a button, but always the application prints the value to be 0.0
my code :

```
 def phAdjustmentWindow(self):
    def scaleResult():
        print(v.get())
        
    v = DoubleVar()    
    phWin= Tk()
    phWin.title("Adjust PH value Manually")
    phScale = Scale(phWin, variable=v, from_=1, to=14, resolution=0.1,width=20,length=300, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    phScale.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)
    backToDefaultValueButton = Button(phWin, text="Default Value")
    phAlertLabel=Label(phWin, text= Constants.PH_MANUAL_ADJUST_ALERT)
    backToDefaultValueButton.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4)
    phAlertLabel.grid(row=2, columnspan=4)
   
    buttonAdjustPhContinueYes = Button(phWin, text="YES", command=scaleResult)
    buttonAdjustPhContinueYes.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
   
    buttonAdjustPhContinueNo = Button(phWin, text="NO")
    buttonAdjustPhContinueNo.grid(row=3,column=2, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: You are apparently calling `Tk()` multiple times in your program.  Each Var is tied to a particular `Tk` instance, and will only work properly with widgets contained in the same instance.  Your `v` obviously isn't tied to `phWin` (which hadn't been created yet), so cannot receive any value from a `phWin` widget.  The simple solution is to call `Tk()` only once, and use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows (that all live in the same `Tk` instance, so there are no restrictions on variable usage).

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you that worked with me